# How to run Spring boot application with STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am starting to learn microservices with Spring Boot. I go to root of my project and run the command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

It works just fine and I can use my endpoints in localhost:8080/[path]. But when I try to run my project from the IDE using Run as -> Spring Boot App. I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

I could just use command line, but I really would like to know why I getting this error with the IDE. So, **what I have to do to run my project from the IDE?**

**Edit 1:**

There is my Main Class:

```
package br.com.leandroborgesferreira.microlearn;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MicroLearnApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroLearnApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: does it display main class name on console along with error? have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451120/spring-boot-program-cannot-find-main-class)

Comment: No. This is the complete error message

Comment: have you checked Run -> Run Configurations? ensure you don't have duplicated main classes

Comment: In the Run Configurations the Main type is: br.com.leandroborgesferreira.microlearn.MicroLearnApplication . So it's correct

Comment: can you post the class in the question.

Comment: Could you also post the full exception log? Are you sure that the IDE, is properly configured to invoke your java app with the same jdk version you are invoking `mvn spring-boot:run` from your command line ? Also could you try simply invoking it as a java app instead of *Run as -> Spring Boot App*

Comment: @AntJavaDev 1- The error message is all the Console shows to me. 2- No... I am not sure, how can I do this? 3- If I try Run as -> Java Application or Run as -> Maven clean I get the same error

Comment: give a look at this [tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/18/spring-boot-support-in-spring-tool-suite-3-6-4). Regarding the jdk , at the run configuration window, there is a tab JRE , check there with which one you are invoking the app.

Comment: This is a Microservice I wrote, it is basically a starter and may be a good base for you to start with, however it is using gradle rather then maven.  https://github.com/Rob-Leggett/gradle_springboot_microservice

Comment: what happens if you create a simple spring boot app using the "new spring starter project" wizard and run that? Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

just right click within `main class` and `run as > spring boot/java application`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case problem was in default maven configurations in Intellij Idea. Go to settings and
Settings -> Build Execution, Deployment -> Maven. Set maven home directory to correct one, not bundled with IJ IDEA.
Right Click the project -> Maven -> Reimport
Then Re-run the project. Hope it work for you too.

Also, please check `Working directory` in 'Run Configuration'. It should be something like "MODULE_DIR"

Comment: Ok. I´ll try it in some hours

Answer (score 0):

Enter **spring-boot:run** in your configuration if using Spring Tools Suite 4 IDE

[image]