# Spring Boot can't find main class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

like mentioned in the title I have a Spring Boot project. Trying to start the project out of my IDE it says, that the main class can't be found.

I've found a relative equivalent question here:
[Spring Boot Program cannot find main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451120/spring-boot-program-cannot-find-main-class)

But the solution doesn't do it for me (I already configured the main class in the pom.xml) like this:

```
<properties>
    <start-class>de.main.Main</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

And this is what my main class looks like:

```
package de.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Main.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Additional to this an other project, which uses Spring Boot aswell, works totaly fine. And the pom.xml is configured the same way in both projects.

I use Spring Boot version 1.5.2 and eclipse oxygen.

The errormessage looks like this:
"Fehler: Hauptklasse de.main.Main konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden"
Roughly translated:
"Error: main class de.main.Main can't be found or loaded"

My Project structure is like this:

```
Project
|--- Java Resources
|       |--- src
|       |     |----de.main
|       |
|       |--- WebContent
|
|--- pom.xml
```

Comment: can you add the error message?

Comment: Its german, but sure:
Fehler: Hauptklasse de.main.Main konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden

Comment: Can you add the directory structure of the project?

Comment: Do you really need to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and override the method? Would you mind trying to get rid of it and run it?

Comment: @Pijotrek
It worked for me in my other project - and getting rid of it doesn't work either. It's still the same problem. :(

Comment: does it run from command line `mvn spring-boot:run` ?
How do you run it from within your IDE ? What IDE is it? Also just noted that your project structure is not maven's default. Is your 'other' project structured in the same way?

Comment: Yea it runs, it trows some errors - gonna check out why...
The IDE is like mentioned in the question "eclipse oxygen"

Comment: @diginoise found the reason for not starting - thanks! Next time I'll try to run it from cmd before asking dump questions... ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason by running the program via. cmd - some unnecessary dependencies caused trouble. Fixed the problem by deleting them.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute the current file like `Run as` -> `Java Application`. Then confirm it is running or not, then you can run the entire project at a time by `Run as` -> `Spring Boot App`. Try to post the directory structure of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Please double-check that your `Main` class is under `src/main/java/de/main/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It worked for me after I did a maven build with goal set to test. (rightclick on project -> run as -> maven build ... -> when prompted what goal put test)