# Adding SourceRoot causes errors in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I created a spring boot application in intelliJ using spring initializr, after I created the project there was no run configuration found. also the DemoApplication.java file was not labeled a class in the project overview nor was it selectable when trying to use it as the main class. I found a stack overflow question([Spring Boot Program cannot find main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451120/spring-boot-program-cannot-find-main-class)) that said to add the class path. when I tried it only two options show up in the drop down oracle and sun(not my class path). I then tried to mark the src folder as source root which helped make the DemoApplication visible by the spring boot configuration 
[image]

Any help on where to go next would greatly be appreciated.

here is my folder structure that was generated by the spring boot initializr. only thing i changed was making src the source root.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mentor</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the pom.xml file?

Comment: Reimport the Maven project, IntelliJ IDEA should configure the source root automatically. If it doesn't work, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. The correct source root is `src/main/java`, not `src`.

Comment: That solved source root it is now 'src/main/java' problem but I am still getting 'DemoApplication is not acceptable' and error messages when trying to build. I added the error messages to the post.

Answer (score -1):

Right click the pom.xml file and select 'Add as Maven'
The icon on your pom.xml file should look like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mUGe.png)

Comment: As per the original question, the project is already a Maven project because the only way you have a pom.xml is by making the project as a Maven project. So how your statement answers the question. Or even if it does so, then could you please elaborate on your answer.