# Not able to run program in Intelij

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, configuration

I try to run or debug program using play/debug button in IntelliJ and I got Error: Could not find or load main class

I've done a lot of things from [Spring Boot Program cannot find main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451120/spring-boot-program-cannot-find-main-class) 
did not work.
But when I use command line and run:  **mvn spring-boot:run** app is running and works perfectly fine.

My main method is below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HomeworkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(HomeworkApplication.class, args);
        JsonData jsonData = new JsonData();
    }
}
```

I just want to run and debug via IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Try out these steps:

- Goto File | Project Structure, or press Crtl+Shift+Alt+S
- Select Modules under the Project Settings section.
- In the Sources tab click Sources on the 'Mark as:' line.
- Click the Apply button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:
Go to Edit Configuration on your main class, then go below the **Before launch: Build, Activate tool window** part and click **+** button and add **Build** if it's not added.