# Error Could not find or load main class springboot eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I can run my first project created correctly (springboot, eclipse), but when I run any of the other projects, the following errors are shown:

[image: error]

[image: errors]

The problem is occurs when I create projects using Spring Boot v2.3.4, but when I use version 2.1.17, projects are built correctly --- obviously it must be a compatibility issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451120/spring-boot-program-cannot-find-main-class

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or a stack trace of your error. it can be helpful to find a solution

Comment: I see although you have added screen shot for description it is added as separate answer. Please add the screen shot in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

**Soln 1.**
You can try updating maven project.

1. Right Click the project -> Maven -> Update Project.
2. Then do maven clean install

OR

**Soln 2.**
From the image it can be seen that it says "it cannot be read or is not a valid zip file". So for all such jar file go to the respective location in .m2 and delete such jar files. Then

1. Right Click the project -> Maven -> Update Project.
2. Then do maven clean install