# Spring boot Build Failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

i am developing a user management API in a spring boot and i made the most needed of entities classes, services and repositories but i missed something that i cant see. I figured out my pom.xml to execute my main class but its dont find it. when i run "./mvnw spring-boot:run" in my project directory its thrown the  build failure below:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class br.com.atosit.UserManagementApiApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.atosit.UserManagementApiApplication
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.792 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-11T20:36:59-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:run (default-cli) on project userManagement-api: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

here my pom.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.atosit</groupId>
    <artifactId>userManagement-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>User Management API</name>
    <description>user Management project for atos IT Apps</description>
    <properties>
        <start-class>br.com.atosit.UserManagementApiApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mappers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

please, i will glad with any help! thanks

Comment: [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451120/spring-boot-program-cannot-find-main-class)

Comment: i am doing that in my "pom.xml" above. something is wrong, i going to review the code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok. I should  be tired and confused.  I Made a wrong configuration in the project pom.xml. there are one  package before the start-class:

wrong configuration:

```
<properties>
    <start-class>br.com.atosit.UserManagementApiApplication</start-class>
</properties>
```

new configuration(startup ok)

```
 <properties>
        <start-class>br.com.atosit.missingpackage.UserManagementApiApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
```