# Error: Could not find or load main class com.javacourse.springBootDemo.SpringBootDemoApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

In Eclipse, when I try to run my SpringBootDemoApplication, it gives me this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.javacourse.springBootDemo.SpringBootDemoApplication 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.javacourse.springBootDemo.SpringBootDemoApplication
```

I have also tried some solutions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451120/spring-boot-program-cannot-find-main-class), but non of them worked...

Here are some of the things I've tried:

**1. Right Click the project -> Maven -> Update Project -> Then Re-run the project.**

*- I did it and nothing happened, same error continues.*

**2. Adding `<start-class>` property in my pom.xml:**

> ```
> <properties>
>     `<start-class>`com.javacourse.springBootDemo.SpringBootDemoApplication</start-class>
> </properties>
> ```

*- Also did nothing. Error still continues.*

**3. I have checked Run -> Run Configurations... and cleared all then tried recreating.**

*- Did nothing as well.*

**4. Checked Window -> Show View -> Problems**

*- Found nothing.*

**5. Tried someone's solution which says: "start-class doesn't work for me, I fixed it by adding build plugins to pom.xml, and executions is necessary."**

> ```
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>repackage</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins> 
> </build>
> ```

*- Did nothing either...*

**6. Did this one too, nothing happened :**

> ```
>  <build> <pluginManagement> <plugins>
>      <plugin>
>          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>      </plugin> </plugins></pluginManagement> 
>  </build>
> ```

**7. Adding the following section in pom didn't help as well...**

> ```
> <plugins>
>     <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <configuration>
>                 <executable>true</executable>
>             </configuration>
>     </plugin>
> </plugins>
> ```

***My POM.XML :***

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <parent>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>       <version>2.6.11</version>
>       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
>   </parent>
>   <groupId>com.javacourse</groupId>
>   <artifactId>springBootDemo</artifactId>
>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   <name>springBootDemo</name>
>   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
>   <properties>
>       <java.version>11</java.version>
>   </properties>
>   <dependencies>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
>
>   <build>
>       <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>               <configuration>
>                   <executable>true</executable>
>               </configuration>
>               <executions>
>                   <execution>
>                       <goals>
>                           <goal>repackage</goal>
>                       </goals>
>                   </execution>
>               </executions>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>   </build>
>
> </project>
> ```

***My SpringBootDemoApplication.class :***

```
package com.javacourse.springBootDemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication; 
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication 
public class SpringBootDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {         
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemoApplication.class, args);   

    }

}
```

***My Package Explorer ScreenShot :***

[image: Package Explorer]

***My Maven and Java Versions :***

> ```
> Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
> Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.8.5
> Java version: 11.0.16, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16
> ```

Thank you all in advance, hope we can solve this vexed issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally solved it. To anyone encountering the same issue and couldn't find a solution : Try to change the project folder destination and move it in C:\ directory. I actually don't know the reason yet but I think that maybe it's related to Maven, JDK or Classpath visibility through C:. But that was the only solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to run the app using the CLI? To discard is it only an eclipse issue

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work either. I get the following error trying to run it through CLI :

Comment: [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.11:run (default-cli) @ springBootDemo ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Error: Could not find or load main class com.javacourse.springBootDemo.SpringBootDemoApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.javacourse.springBootDemo.SpringBootDemoApplication
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.245 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-23T16:46:38+03:00

Comment: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.11:run (default-cli) on project springBootDemo: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]

Comment: I have solved it and added as answer. Thanks anyways!